# Auto execute chrome extension without clicking

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vimeo-player

The extension I am using is called Simple Vimeo Downloader [[Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-vimeo-downloader/mffmjlddchdccijipncbjhoabgmphjfb?hl=en) | [Github](https://github.com/devlab21/simple-vimeo-downloader-extension)]. This extension only works when I manually click it and when it detects a Vimeo Player embedded in the page I am looking at.
I want to auto execute it every time I visit a page which has a Vimeo player embedded in it.

What code changes should I make and where?

Comment: [Inject content script automatically with static declaration](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#static-declarative)

Comment: @iván-nokonoko
I tried this just now, didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/#declaratively), you'd need to include something like this in the `manifest.json` file:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
        "css" : ["insert.css"],
        "js" : ["execute_script.js"],
        "all_frames" : true
    }
],
```

Note that, in order to be injected in all the pages, you need the `<all_urls>` permission, which may delay the extension review time.